# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files when training differential privacy in tensorflow-federated

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I am learning about the function of Differential Privacy in Tensorflow-federated. The following is the display of the first training.
[image]
The break happened  in the 2nd loop like the following.
[image]
Please tell me how to deal with that.

Comment: i would kill all processes or else just try a soft/hard reboot to ensure a fresh environment, in case that helps.

Comment: I have tried, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reset the number of thread, and it works